# Numbers aren't working as values in a SharePoint workflow

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, lookup-column, workflow-activity

I am trying to get a workflow to basically move an item into a certain escalation status and then email someone at that point. We need to calculate only business days, no weekends and no holidays.

I have one SharePoint list of weekends and holidays and columns saying in number format how many days should be paused to skip the weekend or holiday. Then a second list for the cases. That list has lookup columns that pull from the first list. So second list will end up with columns that have just a number in them. 1, 2 or 3 etc. 
[image: Workflow]

Step 1 works great and sets my columns. Step 2 - it will not pause, it just goes straight to step 3 and emails me without the pause. What am I doing wrong here? From playing with multiple lists recently, it SEEMS like the problem is that number 3 in the if current item equals. All other pieces tested work fine, but when I want it to pause when that Lookup:Days column equals a certain number it wont connect the dots. Is there something special about using a number in this field? I have another list where it is text rather than a number and i'm basically doing the same thing and it works just fine. The only other difference besides text is it's not a lookup column.

Then I tried this:
[image: lookup]

Which DOES get it to pause, except it doesn't matter what number is in that column. If it's 3 it pauses for the right amount of time, if it's 5 it pauses for the right amount of time. I feel close, but something is missing! Also i'm not sure if this route makes step 1 pointless (but thats the least of my problems).

Sorry this is so long and hope it makes sense! I'm wracking my brain!